# Batch file for pinging all local IP Addresses

Tags: batch-file

I have been learning Batch Scripting on my own and I can't seem to get one to work.

I want a .bat that pings all IP Addresses on a local network, then prints all the active IPs to a .txt file.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM This script pings all IPAdresses on an Xfinity Router. 
::v1.0 - BTE - 24FEB19
::
FOR /L %i (1,1,254) DO
ping -n 1 10.0.0.%i
```

This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to get the pingable IPs to print to a .txt.

Any help is appreciated!

B.

Comment: `For` needs to be on one line.

Comment: Or at the very least, you need a `(` at the end of the `for` line.

Comment: You need to understand what the term batch file means. It is batches of commands that is executed one after the other. So that said. Your for line ends with do.. Do what? :). So Double your `%` and move the ping line to after do. I.e. `FOR /L %℅i (1,1,254) DO ping -n 1 10.0.0.%℅i`

Comment: Type `for /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the help message; one of the first sentences provides the solution. Anyway, are you sure you want to try to ping one IP after another? if there are a lot of unresponsive ones, you'll have to wait for quite some time. So perhaps take a look at these posts: [Improving Batch File for loop with start subcommand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40964527), [Arrange the pinging of multiple website in order with batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50840684)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
::@ECHO OFF
REM This script pings all IPAdresses on an Xfinity Router. 
::v1.0 - BTE - 24FEB19
::
FOR /L %%i in (1,1,254) DO ping -n 1 10.0.0.%%i | findstr "ms" && (echo 10.0.0.%%i)>>"pingable_ips.txt"
```

- `for` variable in batch file should use `%%`. (On `cmd` prompt use single `%`)
- The loop content needs to be inside a pair of parentheses, or in the same line of `for`.
- You need `in` after the `for` variable.
- And when you are testing, don't use `@echo off` yet.

Here I used the `ms` in the reply message as the signal, you can change it according to your situation.

You can put loop inside a pair of parentheses too:

```
FOR /L %%i in (1,1,254) do (
    ping -w 77 -n 1 10.0.0.%%i | findstr "ms" && (echo 10.0.0.%%i)>>"pingable_ips.txt"
)
pause
```

So you can add other things inside the loop (inside the parens).
Added the `-w` timeout switch, to speed it up, for local ips are quick, you can increase the time.
Check `for /?`, `ping /?`, and `findstr /?` for more.

Comment: The .bat ran, but it didnt create the .txt. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: @BEdwards Could be folder permission, or no local ip pingable(maybe firewall/router/switch blocked icmp packet).  You can remove `echo off`, open `cmd` first, and run the batch inside the `cmd` window, then you can check the commands log, see if you can find some trace in it.

Comment: I ran it from cmd and I can see it pinging all IP addresses, but when it concludes, it doesn't create the txt. I am running it from my desktop, should I put it in a folder?

Comment: @BEdwards  Can you ping local ips manually? Try to write a batch file place at same location, and one just to ping ips, and just to `>>` to a file, see if they're working or not.

Comment: Does the txt file need to already exist?

Comment: @BEdwards Not needed.