# "ping.send()" sometimes fails while "ping" in cmd always works

Tags: c#, network-programming, ping

I have the following c# code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("10.131.88.160");
            int timeout =800;

            Ping pinger = new Ping();

            while (true)
            {
              
                PingReply reply = pinger.Send(ip, timeout, buffer);
                Console.WriteLine(reply.Status);
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(reply.RoundtripTime));
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
```

which should have the same function as following batch:

```
@echo off

cls

set ip=10.131.88.160

:schleife

 ping %ip% -n 1 -w 800 

 timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul

goto schleife
```

The ping test with C# failed every 3~4 attempts, but when using batch every attempt is successful.

Anyone has any clue what can be the reason causing this situation?

I have tried with other IP addresses, with the same results.
Batch file always works, C# sometimes fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dig through the .net [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/84087b4a96d74d446de0c55a06814a03f948e186/src/libraries/System.Net.Ping/src/System/Net/NetworkInformation/Ping.Windows.cs#L169C19-L169C19) for the `Ping` class, it operates by invoking the low-level [IcmpSendEcho2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/icmpapi/nf-icmpapi-icmpsendecho2) function. It has been observed that setting `timeout` to values below `1000` [seems to be unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528336/winapi-why-does-icmpsendecho2ex-report-false-timeouts-when-timeout-is-set-belo).

You can test it yourself. In your code set `timeout=999`, and see the intermittent failures. Now try with `timeout=1000` and it's very likely that they disappear.

As to why the `ping -w 800` in `cmd` works better, it's a mystery. But best guess is that it calls a different low-level function, or it doesn't actually respect the timeout you give it. I can do `ping -w 1` and it would still work fine against machines with `>200ms` ping times.

Comment: It seems that, for batch ping command, when timeout is set less than 2s, it is unrelieable either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456328/the-minimum-value-for-ping-w-timeout-in-practice

Comment: @Cenoce, yeah I didn't bring that one up as it's a little less perscriptive, with a lot of numbers thrown in the post & comments (500ms? 1s? 2s? `-n 1` more reliable?). The `999` vs `1000` on .NET is more clear-cut, with the difference being night and day. Either way, ping on Windows is a really strange beast. And now I'm tempted to check this with .NET on Linux.

Comment: Okay, so I just tested and none of this is an issue on Linux. It's just Windows being Windows.